# Listar datos de un spinner a cajas de texto en anndroid

Tags: android

espetando que todos se encuentren muy bien de salud, para empezar estoy realizando mi primera aplicación en android-studio, ya he aprendido varias cosas, ahora lo que hice con anterioridad que me carque el campo clave en un spinner, ahora lo que quiero hacer es que al escoger un ítem del spinner que me arroje los distintos campos a las diferentes cajas de texto, este es el código que estoy utilizando actualmente:

```
package com.example.prueba1;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.loopj.android.http.*;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText txtid,txtfechadenuncia,txtfechasiniestro,txtsiniestro;
private Spinner spcodigo;
private AsyncHttpClient cliente;
RequestQueue requestQueue;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    txtid = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtid);
    txtfechadenuncia = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtfechadenuncia);
    txtfechasiniestro =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtfechasiniestro);
    txtsiniestro = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtsiniestro);
    spcodigo = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spcodigo);
    cliente = new AsyncHttpClient();
    llenarSpinner();
}


private void llenarSpinner(){
    try {
        String url = "http://192.168.1.87/oficina/buscar_casos.php";
        cliente.get(url, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
                Log.d("WEB", "onSuccess: " + statusCode);
                if (statusCode == 200){
                    cargarSpinner(new String(responseBody));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
                Log.d("WEB", "onFailure: " + statusCode + "\nError: " + error.getMessage());
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void cargarSpinner (String respuesta) {
    ArrayList<Casos> lista = new ArrayList<Casos>();
    try {
        JSONArray jsonarreglo = new JSONArray (respuesta);
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonarreglo.length(); i++) {
            Casos c = new Casos();
            c.setID(jsonarreglo.getJSONObject(i).getString("ID"));
            c.setDenuncia(jsonarreglo.getJSONObject(i).getString("Fecha_Denuncia"));
            c.setSiniestro(jsonarreglo.getJSONObject(i).getString("Fecha_Siniestro"));
            c.setNumero(jsonarreglo.getJSONObject(i).getInt("N_Siniestro"));
            lista.add(c);
        }
        ArrayAdapter<Casos> a = new ArrayAdapter<Casos>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, lista);
        spcodigo.setAdapter(a);
        Thread.sleep(3000);

        spcodigo.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Casos c = lista.get(i);
                String url = "http://192.168.1.87/oficina/buscar_casos.php?ID="+c.getID();
                JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        if (response.length() == 1) {
                            try {
                                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.get(0).toString());
                                txtid.setText(jsonObject.getString("ID"));
                                txtfechadenuncia.setText(jsonObject.getString("Fecha_Denuncia"));
                                txtfechasiniestro.setText(jsonObject.getString("Fecha_Siniestro"));
                                txtsiniestro.setText(jsonObject.getInt("N_Siniestro"));
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Este código no ha sido ingresado aun", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
                requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
                requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
            }
        });

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

después en la línea Thread es donde el problema que no me muestra los datos en las cajas de texto, no sé si eta bien el código ya que estoy trabajando con json a través de php como aprendí a través de internet, favor de ayudarme y desde ya muchas gracias.

Amigos estuve haciendo unas pruebas y me arroja este error:

```
com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: java.io.IOException: Cleartext HTTP traffic to 192.168.1.85 not permitted
```

y el otro es, que piensdo que es lo mismo:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cleartext HTTP traffic to 192.168.1.85 not permitted
```

investigando y leyendo se debe a los permisos, por lo cual mencionan que hay que agregar la siguiente línea:

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

lo hice y no me soluciona el problema, a que se deberá?, disculpen las molestias y desde ya muchas gracias.
Hoy realice una última prueba y lo hice correr, me mostro la aplicación realizando el cambio del clearttraffic y a los segundos se cae, es decir bota y deja de seguir funcionando y busco el error en el logcat y no menciona el posible error, favor de ayudarme para así poder avanzar y seguir aprendiendo.

realizando las últimas pruebas y arreglos me arroja dos errores y del cual me sigue botando de la ejecución, que son las siguientes:

```
JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>()
txtsiniestro.setText(jsonObject.getInt("N_Siniestro"));
```

al parecer no se puede realizar lo que yo pretendo escoger un campo y que se dirijan a cada caja de texto a través del spinner, según código, anteriormente lo había realizado a través de una caja de texto, en el cual el usuario debe digitar el campo, pero para mí esa no es la solución para el usuario.

les comento que ya lo tengo casi solucionado, cambie el código por otro en el spinner, el cual es el siguiente:

```
private void cargarSpinner (String respuesta) {
    ArrayList<Casos> lista = new ArrayList<Casos>();
    try {
        JSONArray jsonarreglo = new JSONArray (respuesta);
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonarreglo.length(); i++) {
            Casos c = new Casos();
            c.setID(jsonarreglo.getJSONObject(i).getString("ID"));
            c.setDenuncia(jsonarreglo.getJSONObject(i).getString("Fecha_Denuncia"));
            c.setSiniestro(jsonarreglo.getJSONObject(i).getString("Fecha_Siniestro"));
            c.setNumero(jsonarreglo.getJSONObject(i).getInt("N_Siniestro"));
            lista.add(c);
        }
        ArrayAdapter<Casos> a = new ArrayAdapter<Casos>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, lista);
        spcodigo.setAdapter(a);
        Thread.sleep(2000);

        spcodigo.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long idl) {
                Casos c = lista.get(position);
                String url = "http://192.168.1.87/oficina/buscar_casos.php?ID="+c.getID();
                cliente.get(url, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
                        Log.d("WEB", "onSuccess: " + statusCode);
                        if (statusCode == 200){
                            txtid.setText(lista.get(position).getID().toString());
                            txtfechadenuncia.setText(lista.get(position).getDenuncia());
                            txtfechasiniestro.setText(lista.get(position).getSiniestro());
                            txtsiniestro.setText(lista.get(position).getNumero());
                        }
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {

                    }
                });
            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

el problema lo tengo como puedo parsear de un int a string en la siguiente línea:

```
c.setNumero(jsonarreglo.getJSONObject(i).getInt("N_Siniestro"));
```

o se cambia en esta:

```
txtsiniestro.setText(lista.get(position).getNumero());
```

ya que el Numero en la case de java la tengo registrada como integer y al ejecutarlo me dice que no lo acepta.

Comment: Mira esta respuesta, está en SO inglés pero es lo que necesitas [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50834600/15298643)

Comment: @javdromero muchas gracias por tu comentario, pero ya lo había visto el día domingo lo leí completo y de acuerdo a las solucones que dieron, me arrojan este resultado en la linea del "JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>()", así que ahora estoy pegado en este error

Comment: Postea tu `network_security_config.xml` y tu `manifest.xml` Además indica qué versión de Android estás usando

Comment: @javdromero muchas gracias por tu ayuda e indicaciones, ya lo había hecho con anterioridad del network y tampoco me funciono y por la versión poseo la 11.0.12 la cual se actualizo en mayo de este año., favor de ver la última edición que realice y nuevamente mil gracias por tu comprensión.

Comment: txtsiniestro.setText(lista.get(position).getNumero() + "");

Comment: @javdromero maestro me funciona muy bien excelente!!!, estoy feliz por lo realizado entre ambos, ahora en mysql el campo de N_Siniestro lo tengo declarado con bigint ya que estos en algunos casos son muy grandes como por ejemplo "9012213001234", y al verlo en android me muestra este "2147483647", a que se deberá, disculpa las molestias y nuevamente mil gracias.

Answer (score 1):

En valor máximo de `Integer` en `Java` es  `2^32 = 4,294,967,296` , por lo tanto el valor máximo positivo es `2,147,483,648`. Estás enviando a setear un valor más grande; `9,012,213,001,234`

Debes de cambiar el tipo de dato de `Numero` a `long`. En la tabla puedes seguir usando `INTEGER` ya que permite hasta 8 bytes de longitud.

A menos que ese valor lo uses para hacer cálculos, todo podría ser `String`, te ahorras conversiones y todo lo anterior.

Comment: muchas gracias por tu ayuda @javdromero